# aws code-build fails on build step image is missing

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

Hi I'm running the aws code pipeline since months now.

Now I got an error:

```
./buildspec_build.sh: line 5: cd: target/docker/stage: No such file or directory
Sending build context to Docker daemon 194.6 kB

Step 1 : EXPOSE 9000
Please provide a source image with `from` prior to commit

[Container] 2017/11/16 15:23:13 Command did not exit successfully chmod +x buildspec_build.sh && ./buildspec_build.sh exit status 1
[Container] 2017/11/16 15:23:13 Phase complete: BUILD Success: false
[Container] 2017/11/16 15:23:13 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: chmod +x buildspec_build.sh && ./buildspec_build.sh. Reason: exit status 1
[Container] 2017/11/16 15:23:13 Entering phase POST_BUILD
[Container] 2017/11/16 15:23:13 Running command echo "*** POST-BUILD:"
*** POST-BUILD:

[Container] 2017/11/16 15:23:13 Running command chmod +x buildspec_postbuild.sh && ./buildspec_postbuild.sh
The push refers to a repository [.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/......]
An image does not exist locally with the tag:
```

My build file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# make code ready for docker
sbt docker:stage
cd target/docker/stage

# add port for aws to dockerfile
echo "EXPOSE 9000" >> Dockerfile

# generate docker image tag
docker build -t "$(cat /tmp/build_tag.out)" .
```

What is my fail? Has aws changed something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was a wrong sbt version. aws changed it.

Answer (score 1):

The first error seems to be that a required folder is missing

```
./buildspec_build.sh: line 5: cd: target/docker/stage: No such file or directory
```

is this supposed to be created manually or by the previous command?

```
sbt docker:stage
```

Comment: yeah but the folder never exists I thought it is created when its needed ... The code worked bevore.

maybe it should be the previous command